# Sharepoint Online API connection from Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, token, office365api, azureportal

I registered an application in Azure Portal and added to it 2 APIs: Azure Active Directory and Microsoft Sharepoint Online with some permissions.
I followed the steps from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/java-tutorial#register-the-app.

The problem is that when I make a request with the Bearer token to the Sharepoint API it gives me an **Unauthorized error: 401**:

***401 Unauthorized
x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"
{"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}***

But when I got the access token I have the these scopes:

"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"AllSites.Manage AllSites.Read AllSites.Write Mail.Read MyFiles.Read MyFiles.Write User.Read"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look of this project i've made that wraps some common operations that you can perform using the Sharepoint Rest API. Its also a very easy to use API

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java

Answer (score 0):

To get SharePoint List data, we can use [Office 365 SDKs for Java](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java) to achieve it.

Or you can check article below to pass Authentication.

[SharePoint REST API Authentication from Java](http://www.chrisweldon.net/sharepoint/sharepoint-rest-api-authentication-from-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Francisco Valle does not cover the case when user uses fedaration account. When user is using federation account then whatever tryies the outcome will be the same:

```
Authentication Failure
<psf:error xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
<psf:value>0x80048821</psf:value>
<psf:internalerror><psf:code>0x80048821</psf:code>
<psf:text>AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password
```

It is because when user uses browser to log in to the SharePoint, there always be redirection to the login page (something like that:

> https://adfs.your_domain.com/adfs/ls/?username=your_user_name&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=)

I have not found yet the way how to overcome this redirection in JAVA, and simply generate the token/ or cookie and pass it when using REST API.